# How to check all checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

jsp code is

```
<input 
    type="button" 
    class="btn btn-theme02 btn-xs " 
    value="CheckAll" 
    onClick="CheckAll(document.myform.checklist)" />
<input 
    type="button"  
    class="btn btn-theme02 btn-xs" 
    value="UnCheckAll" 
    onClick="UnCheckAll(document.myform.checklist)" />
<input  
    type="checkbox" 
    style="width: 20px" 
    class="checkbox form-control centered" 
    id="checklist" 
    name="checklist" 
    value="<%=voucher.getId()%>" />
```

Checkboxes are in a table. Checkbox rows are dynamic.

Javascript:

```
function CheckAll(chk)
{
    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
        chk[i].checked = true ;
}

function UnCheckAll(chk)
{
    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
        chk[i].checked = false ;
}
```

**CheckAll** and **UnCheckAll** buttons are working if there are two or more checkbox.These buttons not working for single checkbox.

Thanks.

Comment: use jquery each to loop through and mark them as check or uncheck.

Comment: Is the `value="<%=voucher.getId()%>"` attribute escaped properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(":checkbox").prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function CheckAll(){
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
          $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
}
function UnCheckAll(){
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
          $(this).prop('checked', false);
});
}
```

and remove anything you are passing as parameter. this should work try it and let me know for any further issue.

Comment: One more thing any element inside html page can have unique id.

Answer (score 0):

In traditional JS:

```
function CheckAll(state) {
    var i = 0,
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (i = 0; inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type === 'checkbox') {
            inputs[i] = state;
        }
    }
}

checkAll(true); // to check
checkAll(false); // to uncheck
```